# AWS kinesis consumer with Java and Spring

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-cloud, amazon-kinesis, spring-cloud-stream

I want to write an AWS kinesis stream consumer in a Spring boot application. And I'm not sure if Spring has a native support of kinesis, or I have to use the [kinesis client library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/developing-consumers-with-kcl.html).

According to [this blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2017/03/09/spring-integration-extension-for-aws-1-1-0-m1-available) `org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-aws` has it ([RELEASE](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.integration/spring-integration-aws) is available in maven repo). However, this example [on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/kinesis-produce-consume) uses `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-kinesis`, which is available only on Spring snapshots repo under `1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`.

**EDIT**: The question is, where can I find an example of `KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not clear what is the question though.

If you are looking for a sample, there is indeed no one. Right the solution we have in Spring is definitely a Channel Adapter for Spring Integration. And that `KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` is exactly consumer implementation for AWS Kinesis:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public static class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter kinesisInboundChannelChannel(AmazonKinesis amazonKinesis) {
        KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter =
            new KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(amazonKinesis, "MY_STREAM");
        adapter.setOutputChannel(kinesisReceiveChannel());
        return adapter;
    }
}
```

The sample you found on GitHub is for Spring Cloud Stream and based on the Kinesis Binder which indeed is still under development.

Comment: Thanks for your response! So is the other project (Kinesis binder) meant to replace Channel Adapter in the future?

Comment: No, it is fully based on that Channel Adapter and just provide the Binder infrastructure for Spring Cloud Stream: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/

Comment: OK, I changed the question to have an example of KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter

Comment: OK. But still not sure what else you would like to hear from our side. You may take a look into tests in the project: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/aws/kinesis/KinesisIntegrationTests.java

Comment: I'll have a look into the tests and try to build an example based on them. If I have more concrete questions, I'll post them. Thanks!